# Typescript compilation returns a lot of errors after VisualStudio 2017 install

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

After VisualStudio 2017 install on my pc I have problem with typescript compilation. Could somebody help with this issue? I can't find any explanation of this behaviour. In VS2015 it also returns same errors. Now I have installed typescript@2.2.2 globally.

**Here is my typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "core-js": "registry:dt/core-js#0.0.0+20160725163759",
    "jasmine": "registry:dt/jasmine#2.2.0+20160621224255",
    "node": "registry:dt/node#6.0.0+20160909174046"
  }
}
```

**Here is my tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

**Here in log from VisualStudio**

> 2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(569,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Number'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(599,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Math'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(619,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'RegExp'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(623,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Map'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(624,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Set'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(625,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'WeakMap'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(626,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'WeakSet'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(627,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Promise'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(628,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Symbol'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(629,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Dict'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(630,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'global'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(631,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'log'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(632,11):
>   error TS2451: Build:Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '_'.
>   2>C:\dev\Marketplace\Marketplace.Web\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts(661,5):
>   error TS2300: Build:Duplicate identifier 'export='.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio 2017 does not yet support TypeScript 2.2, so it's entirely possible new 2.2 syntax has been added to the typings, but is not yet supported by the version of TypeScript used in VS.

More information available at this blog post: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/typescript/2017/03/27/typescripts-new-release-cadence/

If it is not a 2.2 issue, you can toggle off errors in your application by setting `"skipLibCheck": true` inside your `tsconfig.json` `compilerOptions`.